# HTML Canvas: How Do I Set Border Restrictions?

Tags: html, canvas

I have created a program that can move a rectangular block up, down, right, and left within a canvas using the <kbd>w</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> keys. I am having difficulty figuring out how to have the block not go beyond the borders of the canvas and be restricted only to stay within it.

Here is the part of my code for the canvas:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    var positionX=0;
    var positionY=0;

    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, true);

    function draw(){
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas_c");
        var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.fillStyle="green";
        context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, 100, 100);
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
    }
    function onKeyPress(e){ 
        if (e.keyCode==87){
            positionY-=15;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==83){
            positionY+=15;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==68){
            positionX+=50;
        }
        if (e.keyCode==65){
            positionX-=50;
        }
        draw();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstDiv">
        <canvas id="canvas_c" width="1000" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;"> </canvas>

    </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: By removing your title, or otherwise editing the question, we have no clue what your question was and this posting will, or should be, removed unless you fix that.

Comment: Why did you remove the JavaScript code?  The destructive edits you are making are causing this question to become useless.  You question is intended to become a reference and resource for others once you post here.  By deleting content and context, you are causing harm to your post **and** causing yourself to miss out on potential reputation.  Please put that code back so that your question makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pseudo-code for the basic boundary respecting movement functions:

```
// assuming this block object: var block={x:10,y:10,width:20,y:20};
function goLeft(){  if(block.x>0){block.x--;} }
function goUp(){    if(block.y>0){block.y--;} }
function goRight(){ if(block.x<(canvas.width-block.width)){block.x++;} }
function goDown(){  if(block.y<(canvas.height-block.height)){block.y++;} }
```

**[Addition: Here's code based on the code you've added to your question]**

*Warning: untested code ... may need tweaking! :-)*

```
// save the canvas width & height at the top of the app
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

function onKeyPress(e){
    if (e.keyCode==87){
        positionY=Math.max(0,positionY-15);
    }
    if (e.keyCode==83){
        positionY=Math.min(cw-100,positionY+15);
    }
    if (e.keyCode==68){
        positionX=Math.min(ch-100,positionX+50);
    }
    if (e.keyCode==65){
        positionX=Math.max(0,positionX-50);
    }
    draw();
}
```

Comment: In my code, I am using `function draw()` in order to create the rectangular block. How would I be able to implement the pseudocode into the code I already have? I have just put my full html code in my question for clarification.

Comment: I've appended to my answer to show how to refactor your code. I left testing & debugging to you... Good luck with your project!

Comment: I do appreciate your help! I just have one question with the code. What is the significance for the variables cw and ch–what do they do for the code? The block is no longer able to move so I just wanted clarification. Thank you!

Comment: cw & ch are the width and height of the canvas. They are used to create boundaries that your block may not exceed.

Comment: This has helped me so much! Thank you for your time!