# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have created a program that can move a rectangular block up, down, right, and left within a canvas using the w, a, s, and d keys. There is an error when setting a variable to represent the width of the canvas. The error comes up for this line of code:

```
    var cw=canvas.width;
```

I have been trying to use this code on Chrome. Here is the full code:

```
<html>
        <head>
            <script>
            var positionX=0;
            var positionY=0;
            var cw=canvas.width;
            var ch=canvas.height;

            var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");

            window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, true);

            function draw(){
                var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");
                var cw=canvas1.width;
                var ch=canvas1.height;
                var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                context.fillStyle="green";
                context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, 100, 100);
                context.strokeStyle = 'black';
                context.stroke();
            }

        function onKeyPress(e){
            if (e.keyCode==87){
                positionY=Math.max(0,positionY-15);
            }
            if (e.keyCode==83){
                positionY=Math.min(cw-500,positionY+15);
            }
            if (e.keyCode==68){
                positionX=Math.min(ch-500,positionX+50);
            }
            if (e.keyCode==65){
                positionX=Math.max(0,positionX-50);
            }
        draw();
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="firstDiv">
                <canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;"> </canvas>

            </div> 
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is `canvas1` defined ?

Comment: When your script runs, your HTML isn't in DOM yet. Write the script after your HTML

Comment: @user1049876 you really shouldn't edit the title of the question, except to make it more clear. If others want to reference this example they won't search for *Resolved ERROR: SOLVED* It's best to keep the original question, or clarify what the problem was.

Comment: Stop deleting all of the content out of your questions.  You are doing a disservice to your question and to the people that are helping you by removing all of the pertinent information from you question.  You did it in **this** question, and you did it in you *near identical* [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34938358/691711).

Comment: Please stop removing part or all of your question after they have been solved -- if the code is removed then the question will no longer be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [working live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/spencerdcarlson/bq2hd12x/5/)

You should use the `window.onload` function to make sure the HTML gets loaded before trying to access any DOM objects. This syntactically decouples your JavaScript from the HTML.

```
  var positionX = 0;
  var positionY = 0;
  var canvas = {};
  var cw = 0;
  var ch = 0;
  var bw = 100;
  var bh = 100;

 // Set up initial values, after the page loads 
 window.onload = function(){
     positionX = 0;
     positionY = 0;
     canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     cw = canvas.width;
     ch = canvas.height;
     draw();
  };
  // Add keyboard listener
  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, true);

  function draw(){
      canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
      cw=canvas.width;
      ch=canvas.height;
      context=canvas.getContext("2d");

      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.fillStyle="green";

      context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, bw, bh);
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
  }

  function onKeyPress(e){
    var dx = 50;
    var dy = 15;
    if (e.keyCode == 87){
        console.log("w(87) up");
        positionY=Math.max(0,positionY-dy);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 83){
        console.log("s(83) down");
        positionY = Math.min((positionY+dy), (ch-bh));
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 68){
        console.log("d(68) right");
        positionX = Math.min((positionX+dx), (cw-bw));
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 65){
        console.log("a(65) left");
        positionX=Math.max(0,positionX-dx);
    }
    draw();
  }
```

Comment: Very helpful to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some problems are here

```
        var positionY=0;
        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;
```

Here canvas variable is `undefined` . You trying to access `canvas` before settings its value.

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
```

and

```
            var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var cw=canvas1.width;
            var ch=canvas1.height;
```

there is no variable `canvas1` so this should be

```
            var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
            var cw=canvas1.width;
            var ch=canvas1.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");

should be:

var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix:

```
</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstDiv">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;"> </canvas>

    </div>
    <script>
      var positionX=0;
      var positionY=0;
      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
      var cw=canvas.width;
      var ch=canvas.height;


      window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyPress, true);

      function draw(){
          var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
          var cw=canvas.width;
          var ch=canvas.height;
          var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
          context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          context.fillStyle="green";
          context.fillRect(positionX, positionY, 100, 100);
          context.strokeStyle = 'black';
          context.stroke();
      }

      function onKeyPress(e){
        if (e.keyCode==87){
            positionY=Math.max(0,positionY-15);
        }
        if (e.keyCode==83){
            positionY=Math.min(cw-500,positionY+15);
        }
        if (e.keyCode==68){
            positionX=Math.min(ch-500,positionX+50);
        }
        if (e.keyCode==65){
            positionX=Math.max(0,positionX-50);
        }
        draw();
      }
    </script>
</body>
```

Your script related to the canvas dom should not run before the canvas rendered.